# R markdown output filename - use date format

Tags: r, yaml, markdown

I would like to use the date of the most recent Friday in the output filename of my R markdown document. I've tried this code but receive an error message.

```
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding, output_file = paste0('Math-', (format(Sys.Date() - wday(Sys.Date() + 1), '%m-%d-%Y')), '.html')) })
```

> ```
> Error in wday(Sys.Date() + 1) : could not find function "wday" Calls:
> <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> paste0 -> format Execution halted
> ```

I know the filename segment of code works within the console. I'm not sure how to get it to work within the YAML header. I wonder if this isn't working because the package lubridate is needed to run this code chunk. Maybe the question I need answered is if there is a way to obtain last Friday's date using base R? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `lubridate::wday(...)`?

Comment: Yes, that did work. Thank you!